# Test agent and Test Controller

Tags: testing, controller, agent

Failed to register the test agent with the test controller:connection to the test controller failed because either the test controller is inaccessible or tthe service is not running??

Please help me out with this question

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample code ?

Comment: The error is in connection.I am using test agent in virtual machine and test controller in local machine.But I am not able to connect them.The above error shows

Comment: I think both virtual machine and test controller on the same network so that they can connect